# Why does this dictionary go out of range?

Tags: python, pandas

So in my school, we are working on an encoding project making a compression algorithm. I'm working on one that uses a mixture of dictionaries and RLE. I'm currently testing out making an embedded dictionary and placing values into it using pandas. Issue is, something goes out of range somewhere and expands the pd DataFrame, causing the image to be of the wrong shape.
I'm working in Google colab, hence the cv2_imshow import

```
import pandas as pd
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

'''
so the idea is you have a dictionary, with 255 keys for all the different shades of gray and the values for each key has coordinates where each colours belongs per frame
'''

frame_count = 512 # for example, creating a 512x512 dictionary

d = {}
for i in range(512):
  d[i]=0

allframesdict = {}
for frame in range(frame_count):
  allframesdict[frame+1] = d

df = pd.DataFrame(allframesdict)

# printing df.shape print (512,512)

for x in range(512):   # ??
  df.at[x,0]=255 # trying to create a white line as a test

# strangely, assigning x to a variable and printing the variable prints 511

array = df.to_numpy()

# so i decided to try a few things to see what was going wrong
print(type(array))      # prints <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(array.shape)      # prints (512, 513)
print(array)
'''
prints:
[[  0.   0.   0. ...   0.   0. 255.]
 [  0.   0.   0. ...   0.   0. 255.]
 [  0.   0.   0. ...   0.   0. 255.]
 ...
 [  0.   0.   0. ...   0.   0. 255.]
 [  0.   0.   0. ...   0.   0. 255.]
 [  0.   0.   0. ...   0.   0.  nan]]
'''


cv2_imshow(array)
```

cv2_imshow(array) shows (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzLWb.png)

I don't have a clue what's going wrong. Neither does my teacher.

Tried changing (line commented `# ??`) `for x in range(512)` to `for x in range(511)`. Same issue, not much changes other than the x variable ending up as 510.

Tried changing `df.at[x,0]` to `df.at[x+1,0]`. Just causes the dictionary to go even further out of range, changing `print(array.shape)` from (512,513) to (513,513)

Edit:: Even better question that is spur of the moment and I haven't put any thought into, why does the line show on the right side of the array/dictionary/image?

Comment: [tour], [ask], [mre]. the MRE article links to a "how to debug" article. you need to learn debugging. your teacher shouldn't just glance at the issue but debug it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this line

```
df = pd.DataFrame(allframesdict)
```

`df` will contains 1-based columns

```
>>> df.columns
Int64Index([  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,
            ...
            503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 511, 512],
           dtype='int64', length=512)
```

And code

```
for x in range(512):   # ??
  df.at[x,0]=255 # trying to create a white line as a test
```

will add one more column `0` at after `512` column.

```
>>> for x in range(512):   # ??
...   df.at[x,0]=255 # trying to create a white line as a test
...
>>> df.columns
Int64Index([  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,
            ...
            504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 511, 512,   0],
           dtype='int64', length=513)
```

Try

```
for x in range(512):   # ??
  df.at[x,1]=255 # trying to create a white line as a test
```